# Why did Columbia never visit the ISS?

Tags: iss, space-shuttle, shuttle-columbia

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_spaceflights_to_the_International_Space_Station), there were sixteen Space Shuttle missions to the ISS before the loss of *Columbia*; of these, six each were by *Endeavour* and *Atlantis*, four by *Discovery*, and none at all by *Columbia*.

Was there any specific reason why *Columbia* never flew to the ISS, or was it just a freak of chance?

Comment: Short answer: Columbia was heavier than the other (later-built) orbiters, so wasn't as capable of reaching high-inclination orbits.

Comment: Looks like that covers it to me.

Comment: @Sean don't feel bad that your question is closed. It's a good question, and will attract more future readers to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20606/12102) or any other answers that may appear there. You may also be interested in reading answers to [Why was Space Shuttle Atlantis selected for Mir docking so frequently?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20614/12102) and also [How many times has a spacecraft docked with two or more different space stations during a single mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22210/12102) which might make you think of a new question.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Actually, in retrospect, I'm wondering if a desire to retain one orbiter with the internal airlock for non-ISS missions didn't have more to do with it; Columbia should have been able to deliver ~12t of payload to ISS as compared with ~16t for the others.

Comment: I'm away from home so can't confirm but istr the internal a/l was long gone from ov-102.

Comment: WP says "The retention of the internal airlock allowed NASA to use Columbia for the STS-109 Hubble Space Telescope servicing mission, along with the Spacehab double module used on STS-107" but [citation needed].

Comment: @uhoh: No problem - I fully understand.  I do feel a bit stupid right now, but it's not because of the duplicate question - it's because my question would have been answered by _reading through_ Columbia's _Wikipedia article_.  >_<

Comment: @RussellBorogove you're right of course. That's why I never write an answer from memory :) There was an EVA hatch on the tunnel outside, but the airlock was inside. https://science.ksc.nasa.gov/shuttle/missions/sts-107/images/high/KSC-02PD-0977.jpg

Comment: The CAIB report says "Because the airlock was
not located in the payload bay, Columbia could carry longer
payloads such as the Chandra space telescope, which used
the full length of the payload bay. The internal airlock made
the mid-deck more cramped than those of other Orbiters, but
this was less of a problem when one of the laboratory modules was installed in the payload bay to provide additional
habitable volume."